# Особые требования для калькулятора на Java

Tags: java

Есть калькулятор на java, но для него нужны особые условия:

1. Калькулятор умеет выполнять операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления с двумя числами: a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b. Данные передаются в одну строку! Решения, в которых каждое число и арифмитеческая операция передаются с новой строки считаются неверными.
2. Калькулятор умеет работать как с арабскими (1,2,3,4,5…), так и с римскими (I,II,III,IV,V…) числами

   (Пример:
   Input: 1 + 2;    Output: 3;
   Input: VI / III;    Output: II)
3. Калькулятор должен принимать на вход числа от 1 до 10 включительно, не более. На выходе числа не ограничиваются по величине и могут быть любыми.
4. Калькулятор умеет работать только с арабскими или римскими цифрами одновременно, при вводе пользователем строки вроде 3 + II калькулятор должен выбросить исключение и прекратить свою работу.

Как эти пункты возможно реализовать в данном коде?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Calculator {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = getInt();
        int num2 = getInt();
        char operation = getOperation();
        int result = calc(num1,num2,operation);
        System.out.println("Результат операции: "+result);
    }
 
    public static int getInt(){
        System.out.println("Введите число:");
        int num;
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            num = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            num = getInt();
        }
        return num;
    }
 
    public static char getOperation(){
        System.out.println("Введите операцию:");
        char operation;
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
            operation = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе  операции.");
            scanner.next();//рекурсия
            operation = getOperation();
        }
        return operation;
    }
 
    public static int calc(int num1, int num2, char operation){
        int result;
        switch (operation){
            case '+':
                result = num1+num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1-num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1*num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1/num2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Операция не распознана. Повторите ввод.");
                result = calc(num1, num2, getOperation());//рекурсия
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как эти пункты возможно реализовать в данном коде?

В данном коде числа вводятся последовательно из командной строки, также отдельно вводится знак. Эта задача намного проще.
Поэтому вопрос нужно ставить по-другому, что можно взять **из этого кода** для реализации вашей задачи.
 А взять можно принципы ввода данных`scanner.next()` и метод `calc(int num1, int num2, char operation)` для определения знака операции.
Остальное всё нужно писать. Получать строку, парсить, проверять на условия.